# Bcrypt password compare not showing results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I have come accross a strange problem. I have an if statement inside the `bcrypt.compare()`, which doesnt run at all.

**Example**

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, data.password, function (err, result) {

    if (!result || err) {
        res.status(422).json({
            message: "Wrong Password",
            status: false,
            statusCode: 422
        })
    }

});

const otherData = await findOne({
    x : req.body.x
})

if(otherdata.x == "dummy") {

    return res.status(200).json({
        message: "wohhooo"
    })
}
```

When i send wrong password in `request body` it should respond with `message: "wrong password"`

But it skips that `if` statement inside `bcrypt.compare()` and responds with `message: "wohhoo"`

In console I see, `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` with error pointing to `return` statement inside `bcrypt.compare`

Comment: Your using res.status(422).json two times, Note : bcrypt.compare is async function

Comment: I'm sending response only once right>? Can you point out where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent" will throw if your program send multiple response either with res.send() or res.status(422).json()

Comment: Simply change to `return res.status(422).json({
            message: "Wrong Password",
            status: false,
            statusCode: 422
        })`

Comment: It doesn't even make sense. @ŞivāSankĂr

Comment: Check out the answer

Answer (score 1):

`[bcrypt.compare`][1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-check-a-password) is asynchronous function, So your program is executing  `res.status(200).json({message: "wohhooo"})` before `bcrypt.compare`

```
// Quick Fix
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, data.password, function (err, result) {
    if (!result || err) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            message: "Wrong Password",
            status: false,
            statusCode: 422
        })
    } else {
        const otherData = await findOne({
            x: req.body.x
        })
        if (otherdata.x == "dummy") {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: "wohhooo"
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Reference : 
[What the heck is a Callback?](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced)